# For slack, [FIRING] contains [RESOLVED] alert

Tags: prometheus, slack, prometheus-alertmanager

In alertmanager, I set slack and mail on the receiver and compared how they look.

The results are as follows.

> ## mail

3alerts for

[2] Firing

alert1

alert2

[1] Resolved

alert3

---

> ## slack

[FIRING:2]

alert1

alert3 ★

alert2

---

As you can see, the client cannot confirm that alert3 has become RESOLVED.
What configuration files are needed to configure slack notifications in the same way as email notifications?

The current settings are as follows.

**config.yml**

```
  send_resolved: true
  text: |-
    <!channel>
    {{ range .Alerts }}
      *Alert:* {{ .Labels.alertname }} - `{{ .Labels.severity }}`
      *Summary:* {{ .Annotations.summary }}
      *Description:* {{ .Annotations.description }}
      *Details:*
      {{ range .Labels.SortedPairs }} • *{{ .Name }}:* `{{ .Value }}`
      {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
```

We look forward to your answer.

Comment: Is there any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you configured it correctly. `send_resolved: true` must do the trick.

We're using slack & email notifications and `send_resolved` is working fine for both these targets. Please, have a look at Alertmanager's logs. Probably, there was a network issue..

**UPDATE**

Another reason can be that you updated your alermanager's setting after the initial deployment so you expect that new setting will apply dynamically with the help of `prometheus-alertmanager-configmap-reload`container but it often happens that this reload is failing by some reason so what you can do is to delete your alermanager's pod, wait once a new pod is started and see whether it solved your issue or not.

Comment: No, this issue is always reproduced.
Which logs should I look at? Can you share the file name and path?

Comment: What you have to do is just perform `logs` command on your Alertmanager's pod: `kubectl logs -f [name_of_your_alertmanager_pod] -c prometheus-alertmanager`. In case some attempt of email sending failed you will see the reason there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the behaviour of alertmanager, when there are multi-alerts OF THE SAME GROUP/TYPE, only after all alert is resoved,  the status will become "resolved" or it will remain "firing".